# Extract possible sample combinations from multiple count constraints

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, decision-tree, entropy

I have some input data like this.

| unique ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 | 3 |

And my target is to extract some data which satisfy the following conditions:

1. total count: 4
2. `Q1=1` count: 2
3. `Q1=2` count: 1
4. `Q2=1` count: 1~3
5. `Q3=1` count: 1

In this case, both data set with ids [1, 2, 4, 5] or [2, 3, 4, 5] are acceptable answers.

In reality, I will possibly have 6000+ rows of data and up to 12 count limitation like above. The count might varies from 1 to 50.
I've written a solution which firstly group all ids by each condition, then use deapth first search to exhaustedly try out all possible combinations between the groups. (I believe this is a brute-force solution...)
However, I always run out my computer's memory and my time before I can get a possible answer.

My question is,

1. what's the possible least time complexity of this problem. (I believe this is kind of subset sum problem, but I am not sure)
2. how can I solve this problem instead of a brute-force one? I'm considering dynamic programming or decision tree. However, I believe that I will possibly run out of my computer's memory with either of this one. Or can I solve this problem by each data row's probabilities/entropy (and I would appreciate more details on this)?

My brute-force solution sample codes are not worth reading at all. Thus, I'll skip posting my code snippets...

Comment: You can find one solution by posing a linear programming problem, for example by using `pulp` with Python. You will have `n` binary variables indicating if a row should be included, and the constraints should be possible to define given the values in the dataframe.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem
Thanks for your recommendation!
I found out that this is indeed a integer programming problem.
I've already found an answer to approximate the result.
I will try to answer this question once I have time haha